# Why does SSH Server (Ice Cold Apps) with a command fail?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, root-access, samsung-galaxy-s-4, shell, ssh

I wish to ssh into my rooted Android Samsung Galaxy S4 v4.4.2 phone and run a command.  I have SSH Server installed.  If I just SSH, it works fine:

```
bash-3.2$ ssh -p 35151 10.1.10.22 
u0_a253@jfotevzx:/ $ pwd
/
```

But, if I pass a command to execute to ssh it fails:

```
bash-3.2$ ssh -p 35151 10.1.10.22 pwd
exec request failed on channel 0
```

What does `exec request failed on channel 0` mean? How can I get the SSH Server from Ice Cold Apps to work with a command to execute?  Is there a different ssh android app that I could use instead that would work?

Answer (score 1):

I [found a forum post](http://androidforums.com/threads/why-cant-i-execute-command-remotely-using-ssh.757079/) that indicates that the Ice Cold ssh has a deficiency that causes this issue.  By switching to SSH Droid, I was able to resolve the issue.

Comment: I tried this app just now and was able to reproduce this error. On the other hand, [Servers Ultimate Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimatepro) doesn't have any said issues. It worked well with the command you mentioned in the question.